# OpenSSH server wont install on azure Windows 10 VM

Tags: azure, openssh

I'm trying to install OpenSSH-Server on multiple Windows 10 VM from Azure.
I added some rules on network security group (directly on portal.azure) : I allowed inbound traffic for port 22 and same for outbound.

After that I tried to install openSSH-server using the windows 10 interface, but it doesn't work (no error message, just jumping back into the app list).

I tried to add the rules to the firewall and retried to install openSSH-server, no success.

I also tried to install it using powershell but without success.

There is something I must be missing, here is the guide I followed for installing OpenSSH-server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

And here is the guide I followed for opening ports:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally find out what was blocking the installation, the Windows update service was deactivated, by activating it I was able to install OpenSSH-Server, all good now !